# Project file structure, how to reduce SASS compilation time in compass when you have a lot of pages?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-watch

For a project I am using SASS 3.2.19 and Compass 0.12.5 combined with the last version of Grunt.

My file structure looks like this :

```
styles/
    css/
      page1.css
      page2.css
      page3.css
      ...
    sass/
      page1.scss
      page2.scss
      page3.scss
      ...
      generics/
         _general.scss
         _menu.scss
         _ie.scss
         ...
      partials/
         _sectionBegin.scss
         _sectionClients.scss
         ...
```

In each pages{number}.scss file I import the scss blocks I actually need like this :

```
@import "generics/general"; // inside this file _ie.scss is imported
@import "generics/menu";
@import "partials/sectionBegins";
@import "partials/sectionClients";

.additionalStyles {
    background: url(/example/example-cover.jpg) no-repeat;
 }
```

And finally, here is my Gruntfile.js :

```
compass: {
     dev: {
        options: {
           sassDir: ['styles/sass'],
           cssDir: ['styles/css'],
           outputStyle: 'expanded',
           noLineComments: true,
           environment: 'development'
        }
     },
...
grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass:dev' , 'watch']);
```

So, what I am doing here is setting Grunt to watch the sass/ repository. As soon as it detects some changes the page.css will be overwrite.

Well, this project structure actually works perfectly when there are only a few pages but now that I have more than 40 pages the compilation time is taking approximately 1min.
Indeed supposed that I edit a .scss file which is used by all the pages, all the pages will have to be overwritten.

So, what I am missing here ? How can I improve my project file structure and do you have some good examples of a gruntfile conf in a similar scenario ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also have a Sass project with a lot of partials. We still haven't figured out what to do when modifying a partial that is used by a lot of .scss files; there really isn't a way to get around having to compile all of them (eventually, when you deploy; sometimes you're only working on one page and really do only need one to compile in the short term). You could set up grunt tasks to compile each of your pages individually so you at least have something to run when you only need to compile a single .scss file.

The best thing to do in your case might be to think outside the box here...what if that partial WASN'T required by a lot of .scss files? What if it was only imported into one main.scss file that compiled into a minified main.css that was included on every page of your project (as the first script on the page, so its styles would get overwritten by any more specific page styles)? We have one script that includes our generic styles for things like buttons, forms, panels...stuff that's on pretty much every page, and isn't too large a burden to load in on pages that don't have a form or a button, especially if minified.

For the cases where modifying a partial only needs to prompt compilation of a few Sass files, we have figured out a solution using the Gruntfile. You can use grunt-contrib-watch to run different tasks depending on where a change was detected. For example, we have the following 2 tasks set up for grunt-contrib-sass:

```
sass: {
    dev_mainstyles: {
        options: {
            sourcemap: true,
            trace: true,
            style: 'expanded',
            compass: true,
            lineNumbers: true
        },
        files: {
            '...css/main.css': '...sass/main.scss',
        },
    },
    dev_customerstyles: {
        options: {
            sourcemap: true,
            trace: true,
            style: 'expanded',
            compass: true,
            lineNumbers: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.../sass/',
            src: ['customers/**/*.scss'],
            dest: '.../css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }],
    },
}
```

I have set up the following tasks for grunt-contrib-watch:

```
watch: {
    sassmain: {
        files: ['.../sass/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dev_mainstyles'],
    },
    sasscustomers: {
        files: ['.../sass/customers/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dev_customerstyles'],
    },
}
```

By listing both files and directories you can get as specific as you need to and hopefully you'll be able to set up watch tasks that only compile what is needed whenever something changes! Good luck!

We're still looking for suggestions on how to make this whole process even faster, by the way, this is by no means a definitive answer, it's just some tricks we've figured out so far.

Comment: Clever & detailed solution :-). Thanks for sharing!